# async for loop in express.js

Tags: javascript, html, express, web

I am trying to show all images with for loop. I have saved paths of images in Cubeimage array. And now I am trying to display them in `<img>`, but I get an error. How to write async code so it would work?

```
<div class="row">
 <% for (var i = 0; i < Cubeimage.length; i++) { %>
  <div class="column rounded border d-flex align-items-center">
    <img class="demo cursor align-middle" src="<%= Cubeimage[i].image_path; =%>" style="width:100%;" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="The Woods">
</div><% } %>
```

> Error:missing ) after argument list in /home/ubuntu/back_end/views/products_cube.ejs while compiling ejs If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint: github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass async: true as an option. SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in /home/ubuntu/back_end/views/products_cube.ejs while compiling ejs

Comment: Error:missing ) after argument list in /home/ubuntu/back_end/views/products_cube.ejs while compiling ejs If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint: https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass async: true as an option.
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in /home/ubuntu/back_end/views/products_cube.ejs while compiling ejs

Comment: Add additional informations using the [edit] button of the question, and not the comment section.

Comment: @Emilis Did you find the solution or ?

Comment: When you found the solution yourself then add it to the answer section, and accept it. Don’t add the solution to the question section.

Comment: I moved your answer to the answer section and created a community wiki answer, but you are free to create a personal answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution found by the OP, and originally added to the answer:

```js
<div class="row">
  <% Cubeimage.forEach(function(cube){ %>
    <div class="column rounded border d-flex align-items-center">
      <img class="demo cursor align-middle" src="<%= cube.image_path; %>" style="width:100%;"       onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Cube">
    </div>
  <% }); %>
</div>
```